# How to append a input field with the type 'submit'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently looping through and appending the following information. It is appending fine but I am having problem when I append . By default it is coming as a text but I want it to be submit.

When I try to append it as follows, it doesn't work. (Blank screen)

```
 $("<input type="submit"/>",{
                text:"Paid"
            }).appendTo(wrap);
```

Please advice how I can append it a a type 'submit' . Thanks.

```
$.each(data,function(elem){
            var wrap = $("<div/>").attr('data-role', 'collapsible');
            identity.push(data[elem].id); 
            //Create the h1 and the other elements appending them to bills List
            $("<h1/>",{
                text:data[elem].reference
            }).appendTo(wrap);   
            $("<p/>",{
                text:"Account: "+ data[elem].account
            }).appendTo(wrap);        
            $("<p/>",{
                text:"Amount: "+ data[elem].amount
            }).appendTo(wrap);
            $("<input/>",{
                text:"Paid"
            }).appendTo(wrap);
            wrap.appendTo('#unpaidList');             
        })//end of for each loop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try put the submit inside `''`:

```
 $("<input type='submit'/>",{
                text:"Paid"
            }).appendTo(wrap);
```

Comment: Works. I am unable to see the syntax error at all on my Sublime ide.

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes when you are inside double quotes, because this way it's a simple syntax error.

Your code should look like this:

```
 $("<input type='submit'/>",{ text:"Paid" }).appendTo(wrap);
```

I suggest you to use the browser's JavaScript console, because that would surely indicate syntax errors immediately. Or even better if you use a tool such as [FireBug](https://getfirebug.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
$('<input>').prop('type', 'text'):
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a button, you may as well use a button tag...

```
$('<button/>', {
      type: 'submit',
      text: 'Paid'
}).appendTo(wrap);
```

as an input tag:

```
$('<input/>', {
      type: 'submit',
      text: 'Paid'
}).appendTo(wrap);
```

Comment: I am using jquery mobile thud wanted to maintain the css for the input but seems no use and looks the same as an ordinary button.